# Get list of last record for each ID in SQL

Tags: sql, record

I would like to get last records by every id_foreign in sql, example what I want to do:

**input:**

```
id: 1, id_foreign: 5, value: 1 
id: 2, id_foreign: 4, value: 2 
id: 3, id_foreign: 4, value: 3 
id: 4, id_foreign: 5, value: 4 
id: 5, id_foreign: 5, value: 5
```

**output:**

```
id: 3, id_foreign: 4, value: 3 
id: 5, id_foreign: 5, value: 5
```

What about *DISTINCT*? Any other idea? Understand me?

**tried this solution:**

```
SELECT * FROM table 
GROUP BY id_foreign 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

**but outputs me:**

```
id: 1, id_foreign: 5, value: 1 
id: 2, id_foreign: 4, value: 2
```

I tried both (ASC and DESC) and bad output too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple but not necessarily the most optimal way of querying this is using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM MyTable tt WHERE tt.id_foreign=t.id_foreign AND tt.id > t.id
)
```

[Demo on SqlFiddle.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/984a5/3)